# Theme is fine on localhost but breaks on live server

Tags: php, wordpress

My Wordpress theme works fine on my localhost yet when I activate it on my live server I am getting the following breaking error...

```
[30-Jun-2016 13:06:19 UTC] PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /home/launchcode/public_html_staging/wp-content/themes/launchcode/functions.php on line 13
```

Line 13 in my functions.php file is the following (lines above this are comments)

```
$sage_includes = [
  'lib/assets.php',    // Scripts and stylesheets
  'lib/extras.php',    // Custom functions
  'lib/setup.php',     // Theme setup
  'lib/titles.php',    // Page titles
  'lib/wrapper.php',   // Theme wrapper class
  'lib/customizer.php' // Theme customizer
];
```

Please note that other themes work fine on my live server. Does anyone have any idea as to why this might be causing an error? I'm thinking maybe it's to do with the PHP versions but not 100%.

Local PHP Version: 5.5.10
Local Apache Version: 2.2.26

Live PHP Version: 5.5.30
Live Apache Version: 2.4.16

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Doesn't sound like the server is on the PHP version you think it is. Sounds more like 5.3 which doesn't support the short array `[]` syntax.

Comment: It's 100% your PHP versions. The `[]` syntax wasn't introduced until PHP 5.4 and you get that exact error otherwise. Are you sure your live server is using the PHP version you think? You could be running a later version in CLI and an earlier version on your Apache. You should run a page with `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` in the same area as your Wordpress site.

Comment: Ah awesome, just changed the cpanel php version to 5.4 and it started working! Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your PHP version to 5.4 or above, as other's have commented.